# How to add new array in to existing array dynamically using session in codeigniter

Tags: arrays, codeigniter, session, concatenation

i want to store multiple array in same session on every function call .. my function is given below.

function store_item($param='')
    {

```
    $count = count($this->session->userdata('items_array'));
    echo $count;
    $count++;
    $item_id = $this->input->post('product_id');
    $data[][$count] = $this->Quotation_model->get_data_single($item_id);


    $this->session->set_userdata('items_array',$data);


}
```

i want this result

Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => Check [category_id] => 1 [supplier_id] =>  ) ) Array ( [1] => Array ( [name] => Check [category_id] => 1 [supplier_id] =>  ) ) Array ( [2] => Array ( [name] => Check [category_id] => 1 [supplier_id] =>  ) ))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this you are overwriting session array each time

```
$data = $this->session->userdata('items_array');
echo $count;
$count++;
$item_id = $this->input->post('product_id');
$data[] = $this->Quotation_model->get_data_single($item_id);
$this->session->set_userdata('items_array',$data);
```

Here you are first get session details to variable then add new item details to same variable to set session again with new data